# "Mazlum getirin bana" - What is the story behind this bit?

Tags: dialogue, comedy

I don't speak Turkish, but I've recently noticed a couple of references to an apparent trope, or at least iconic bit, in Turkish cinema, in which a protagonist says "Mazlumu getirin bana", which means something like "Get me Mazlum" or "Get Mazlum in here" or "Bring Mazlum here":

[Mazlum clip on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBSyAQHM3IY)

My question: What's the context of this piece of dialog, and why is it used outside the context of the film?